# youtube comment number scraping with youtube

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, youtube

in my  project i have tried to scrape youtube viewers number, comment number , likes and dislikes numbers. I cant take comments number i have tried different methods but nothing change. here is my code please help me :

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd
import time

from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

#we choose our browser chromedriver must be in the path
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

#we need data to save variables

data = {'Likes' : [], 'Dislikes' : [], 'Comments' : [], 'Views' : []}

dataframe = pd.DataFrame(data)

# we  get the link 

driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fHI8X4OXluQ")

# we wait for opening the link
time.sleep(5)

# we find element by xpatch which means manually
Likes = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/ytd-app/div/ytd-page-manager/ytd-watch- 
flexy/div[5]/div[1]/div/div[8]/div[2]/ytd-video-primary-info- 
renderer/div/div/div[3]/div/ytdmenu-renderer/div[2]/ytd-toggle-button-renderer[1]/a/yt- 
formatted-string').text

Dislikes = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/ytd-app/div/ytd-page-manager/ytd-watch- 
flexy/div[5]/div[1]/div/div[8]/div[2]/ytd-video-primary-info-renderer/div/div/div[3]/div/ytd- 
menu-renderer/div[2]/ytd-toggle-button-renderer[2]/a/yt-formatted-string').text

View = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@id="count"]')

Comments=driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/ytd-app/div/ytd-page-manager/ytd-watch- 
flexy/div[5]/div[1]/div/ytd-comments/ytd-item-section-renderer/div[1]/ytd-comments-header- 
renderer/div[1]/h2/yt-formatted-string/span[1]')


print(Likes)
print(Dislikes)
print(View[1].text)
print(Comments)




driver.quit()
```

Comment: Its always a good practice to write relative xpaths

Answer (score 0):

Basically something like this should work

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd
import time

from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

#we choose our browser chromedriver must be in the path
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

#we need data to save variables

data = {'Likes' : [], 'Dislikes' : [], 'Comments' : [], 'Views' : []}

dataframe = pd.DataFrame(data)

# we  get the link 

driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fHI8X4OXluQ")

# we wait for opening the link
time.sleep(5)


likes_xpath = '(//div[@id="top-level-buttons-computed"]//*[contains(@aria-label," likes")])[last()]'
# we find element by xpatch which means manually
Likes = driver.find_element_by_xpath(likes_xpath).text

dislikes_xpath = '//div[@id="top-level-buttons-computed"]//*[contains(@aria-label," dislikes")]'
Dislikes = driver.find_element_by_xpath(dislikes_xpath).text

views_xpath = '//*[name()="ytd-video-view-count-renderer"]/span[@class="view-count style-scope ytd-video-view-count-renderer"]'
View = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(views_xpath)

comments_xpath = '//*[name()="ytd-comment-renderer"]//*[name()="yt-formatted-string" and @id="content-text"]'
Comments=driver.find_elements_by_xpath(comments_xpath)


print(Likes)
print(Dislikes)
print(View[1].text)
print(Comments)


driver.quit()
```

However there are a lot of comments there, so in order to get all of them you will have to scroll this page

Comment: NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@id="top-level-buttons-computed"]//*[contains(@aria-label," likes")]"}
  (Session info: chrome=91.0.4472.77)

it gives me that error :(

Comment: If i only use comments part of the code, everything is fine except comment. The comment return me as empty list.

Comment: well, the page is normally opened with the video taking the full screen so that the comments are not on the visible screen. I guess this can cause empty comments list

Comment: the page isn't opening full screen at my chrome.exe. I have tried that edited code but its still the same error. Code cant locate the element. I have also tried to scroll the page but it does not help.

Answer (score 0):

See if this works for comments count:-

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[@class='style-scope ytd-comments-header-renderer' and @id='title']//following-sibling::yt-formatted-string[contains(@class,'ytd-comments-header-renderer')]/span[1]") 
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", elem)
elem.text
```

Comment: I'm sorry but it does not work.

NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//div[@class='style-scope ytd-comments-header-renderer' and @id='title']//following-sibling::yt-formatted-string[contains(@class,'ytd-comments-header-renderer')]/span[1]"}
  (Session info: chrome=91.0.4472.77)

Comment: You have to bring the comments counts webelement into view. Updated the code

Comment: still i got the same error, we cant find the element. Should i try to use firefox explorer?

Comment: i tried in the chrome browser and it worked